# Alias Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have this query in sequelize:

```
    Domicilio.hasMany(User, {foreignKey: 'UserId'});
    const abonados = await Domicilio.findAll({include: User});
```

Which result is the following:

SELECT `domicilio`.`DomicilioId`, `_users`.`UserId` AS `_users.UserId`, `_users`.`UserName` AS `_users.UserName`, `_users`.`FullName` AS `_users.FullName`, `_users`.`Password` AS `_users.Password`, `_users`.`Documento` AS `_users.Documento`, `_users`.`Cuit` AS `_users.Cuit`, `_users`.`Email` AS `_users.Email`, `_users`.`FechaBajada` AS `_users.FechaBajada`, `_users`.`FechaContrato` AS `_users.FechaContrato`, `_users`.`FechaNacimiento` AS `_users.FechaNacimiento`, `_users`.`Phone` AS `_users.Phone`, `_users`.`FailedPasswordCount` AS `_users.FailedPasswordCount`, `_users`.`IsActive` AS `_users.IsActive`, `_users`.`IsLocked` AS
`_users.IsLocked`, `_users`.`IsTestUser` AS `_users.IsTestUser`, `_users`.`LastLoginDate` AS `_users.LastLoginDate`, `_users`.`createdAt` AS `_users.createdAt`, `_users`.`createdBy` AS `_users.createdBy`, `_users`.`deletedAt` AS `_users.deletedAt`, `_users`.`deletedBy` AS `_users.deletedBy`, `_users`.`updatedAt` AS `_users.updatedAt`, `_users`.`updatedBy` AS `_users.updatedBy`, `_users`.`CondicionIVAId` AS `_users.CondicionIVAId`, `_users`.`OnuId` AS `_users.OnuId`, `_users`.`ServicioId` AS `_users.ServicioId` FROM `domicilio` AS `domicilio` LEFT OUTER JOIN `_user` AS `_users` ON `domicilio`.`DomicilioId` = `_users`.`UserId`;

But I don't need the ALIAS of each of the columns of table _user. E.g _user.UserId  I need only the name of each column without alias.  Is there any way to aproach this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to change the value of the returning column

- First I would suggest that you fetch only the columns really needed
  by you at the model endpoint that way the response is concise.

  Please refer the code below in which you can see how you can provide
  alias  in an association, the alias you provide in there is the one
  which is used during the include you can fiddle around to get the
  desired behavior. Also, you can tweak your `findAll` with option
  params like `{raw: true}`

  > Official Docs:
  >
  > https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html
  >
  > [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll)

  ```
  Ship.belongsTo(Captain, { as: 'leader' }); // This creates the `leaderId` foreign key in Ship.

  // Eager Loading no longer works by passing the model to `include`:
  console.log((await Ship.findAll({ include: Captain })).toJSON()); // Throws an error
  // Instead, you have to pass the alias:
  console.log((await Ship.findAll({ include: 'leader' })).toJSON());
  // Or you can pass an object specifying the model and alias:
  console.log((await Ship.findAll({
    include: {
      model: Captain,
      as: 'leader'
    }
  })).toJSON());
  ```

---

- Second but not very recommended way is to provide a raw query with
  the parameter [Do not use javascript template string to pass the
  args] here you have control over the params and conditions

  > Docs for raw query: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

---

- Lastly, you can use alias in attribute to customize the value's key
  to anything you like

  ```
  const abonados = await Domicilio.findAll({
     include: User,
     attributes: [['UserId', 'newUserId'], ['UserName 'newUserName']]
  });
  ```

P.S: [literal](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-literal) might also come in handy at times.